# Show GtkApplicationWindow after close

Tags: c, gtk, glade

I am a complete newbie when it comes to C and Gtk+.

I am trying to create an interface with a main application window. This main window has a menu, which opens a second window (of type GtkApplictionWindow).

My problem is, that once I close this second window (with the x in the top) I cannot open this second window again.

I get an error:

```
(api:2807): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_show: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
```

I've tried attaching a function to both the `destroy` and the `hide` signals, and in my code I've tried both `gtk_widget_destroy(window_connections)` and `gtk_widget_hide(window_connections)`.

My interface is created in Glade.

Here is my current code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdio.h>

GtkWidget       *window_connections;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GtkBuilder  *builder;
    GtkWidget       *window;
    GtkWidget       *statusbar;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "glade/window_main.glade", NULL);

    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window_main"));
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

    window_connections = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window_connections"));

    statusbar = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "statusbar"));

    gtk_statusbar_push(GTK_STATUSBAR(statusbar), 1, "Hello, World!");

    g_object_unref(builder);

    gtk_widget_show(window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}

// called when window is closed
void on_window_main_destroy() {
    gtk_main_quit();
}

void window_open_connections() {
    gtk_widget_show(window_connections);
}

void window_close_connections() {
    gtk_widget_hide(window_connections);
}

void window_hide_test() {
    printf("hide\n");
}
```

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you close a Window using the "X", it will be not only hidden but also destroyed afterwards.
Obviously you cannot reuse that widget later. You would need to create it again.

This is where [`gtk_widget_hide_on_delete()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-hide-on-delete) comes in handy.

You can directly connect it to the `"delete-event"` signal or you can call it from within your handler for that signal.
Then the widget is only hidden but can be shown again later.